# Reading from file results in accented "a"'s in the spaces

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read [this text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxIMC.png), taking only the action and parameter, and ignoring everything including and after the forward slashes (only "NCORES 2", "SLICE 100", etc). It manages to separate "NCORES" and "2" as a string and integer, as intended. However, [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W44O.png). Apparently, it's reading the whole of "SLICE 100" as the parameter, and isn't going to the next line. I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
        string action;
        int parameter;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };

int main() {
    int time = 0; //in milliseconds
    string action;
    int parameter;
    string misc;

        /*node* head;
        node* tail;
        node* n;

        n = new node;       //makes new node and n points to it
        n->parameter = 1;
        n->prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;

        n = new node;
        n->parameter = 2;
        n->prev = tail;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
        */

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        cin>>action>>parameter;
        //cout<< action << parameter<<endl;
        cout<< action <<endl;
        if(i==0){
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n'); //Ignore until new line
        }
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your text file and output should be posted in text format within your question. Also you should provide a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. By "minimal", I mean that you should strip out all the unnecessary, irrelevant stuff like the commented-out code and the unused node structure.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the thing in the text document is not spaces (U+0020). They are non-breaking spaces (U+00A0). My psychic powers tell me that you are printing them as mojibake in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), in which A0 represents `á`.